# Mathematica not giving real roots when computing roots of cubic equation

Tags: equation-solving

Here's the code and corresponding output

> soln = NSolve[
> 541.5535677 == (1/V) + (1.57x10^-4/V^2) + (9.56x10^-3/V^3), V]

> {{V -> -0.0124127 - 0.0225339 I}, {V -> -0.0124127 +
> 0.0225339 I}, {V -> 0.026672}}

I believe this equation should have three real roots yet I am getting two complex and one real root. Please help!

Comment: Your question arises from misunderstanding of basic mathematical concepts and it weakly related to the computer system *Mathematica*.  Third order polynomial with real coefficients may have only one real root.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as @Artes remarked has to do with the underlying maths and not the software itself.

Comment: If you plot the curve after putting everything on one side of the equation, you will see that it crosses the x-axis in only one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematica is correct.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Converting to an exact equation,

```
eqn = 541.5535677 == (1/V) + (1.57*10^-4/V^2) + (9.56*10^-3/V^3) // 
    Rationalize[#, 0] & // Simplify;
```

The numeric values of the exact solution

```
(soln = Solve[eqn, V]) // N

(* {{V -> 0.026672}, {V -> -0.0124127 - 0.0225339 I}, {V -> -0.0124127 + 
    0.0225339 I}} *)
```

Verifying the exact solution,

```
eqn /. soln // Simplify

(* {True, True, True} *)
```